# What is wrong with my mint function?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm trying to call the mint2 function from my React application using contract.callStatic. However, it is throwing the following error in my console:

```
error:  Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="mint2(address,string,string)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.1)
```

I've inspected `provider.getCode(address)` and it seems to return 0x despite me having deployed the contract onto Rinkeby and being connected to the correct wallet network.

I suspect the issue is in my solidity mint2 function.

Here is my code in full:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

// We first import some OpenZeppelin Contracts.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract CharityNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

  // We need to pass the name of our NFTs token and its symbol.
  constructor() ERC721 ("CharityNFT", "CHAR") {}

  function mint2(address to, string memory tokenURI, string memory receiptURI) payable external returns (uint256) {
    require(msg.value > 0 wei, 'Mint requires a donation of at least 1 wei.');
    
    // mint secret message
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 secretMessageId = _tokenIds.current();
    _safeMint(to, secretMessageId);
    _setTokenURI(secretMessageId, tokenURI);

    // mint receipt
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 receiptItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _safeMint(msg.sender, receiptItemId);
    _setTokenURI(receiptItemId, receiptURI);

    // pay the donation
    payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);

    return secretMessageId;
  }
}
```

In my React App, I have the following that calls the `mint2` solidity function:

```js
async function mint(
  receiverWalletAddress: string,
  tokenURI: string,
  receiptURI: string
) {
  if (!web3Provider) return console.log('no provider connected.')
  if (!contractAddress) return console.log('no contract address!! ')

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    contractABI.abi,
    web3Provider.getSigner()
  )

  // Error is being thrown from this line.
  const secretMessageId = await contract.callStatic.mint2(
    receiverWalletAddress,
    tokenURI,
    receiptURI,
    {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.005'),
    }
  )
  // I do not see the following log in my console.
  console.log('secretMessageId: ', secretMessageId)
  await contract.mint2(receiverWalletAddress, tokenURI, receiptURI, {
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.005'),
  })
}
```

Comment: provider.getCode(address) = 0x means the contract is not deployed correctly or you are connected mistakenly to another network or node provider is not reachable

Comment: Thanks @MajdTL, I get that. I'm connected to the correct network and my contract is deployed to that network as seen here https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x1fc7fe607ba2481ff492814c27943dedb8cba0ce

The issue as you can see in the contract's transaction history is there have not been any mints...

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue... The URL in my hardhat config was pointed to the wrong network on Alchemy.